# Can the OIDC "jwks_uri" URI defined in the "/.well-known/openid-configuration" be cached?

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, openid-connect

I'm writing a service which requires OIDC. I've seen a number of client libraries (the programming language and library here is irrelevant) which allow auto-refreshing/re-fetching the content at the "jwks_uri" endpoint which is defined in the discovery document at the IdP's "/.well-known/openid-configuration" endpoint.

I know the content defined at the actual "jwks_uri" endpoint can change.  But can the value of this "jwks_uri" (the URI itself) change in the discovery document?  I can't seem to find any answer in the specs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be cached. For example some clients (like in .NET) do for example cache this information (including the singing keys) and refresh this information every 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

If you validate your token remotely (in the IDP side) yes you can cache the content of .Well-known for ever, in the most case the endpoints of your IDP will never change, but if you validate your token locally, you need the last keys in IDP side, and you need to know the frequency change of keys in your IDP, basing on that you can cache your keys.